# Hiding text in an input field after pressing space bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make an input field that allows to only see one word at a time. For example, if a user wants to type 'Hello world!' on the input field,
they should get the following result.

```
Typing 'Hello'

+-------------------------+
+Hello|                   + 
+-------------------------+

Pressing space bar
+-------------------------+
+|                        + 
+-------------------------+

Typing 'world!'
+-------------------------+
+world|                   + 
+-------------------------+
```

- The previously written words should be accessible when pressing backspace

```
After deleting 'world!' we should get 'Hello' again.
+-------------------------+
+Hello|                   + 
+-------------------------+
```

- This should be done in plain JavaScript and css; jQuery and other libraries are not an option

Here is a simulation to demonstrate the desired result.

html

```
<div class="container">
<p> The desired output when a user starts typing</p>
<input type="text" id="simulateTyping">


<p> When a user presses space bar, they should get the effect shown above but in the same input field. </p>
<p> The previously written text should be accessible when pressing backspace</p>
<input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Start typing to see the effect" onkeypress="start()">
</div>
```

css

```
    body {
        text-align: center;
        font-family: monospace;
    }

    .container {
        margin: auto;
        width: 500px;
        border: 1px solid #eee;
        font-size: 17px;
    }

    input {
        width: 300px;
        height: 40px;
        font-family: inherit;
        font-size: inherit;
    }
```

JavaScript

```
    var myInput  = select('myInput');
    var myOutput = select('simulateTyping');
    var notStarted  = true;
    var typed;

    Array.prototype.lastIndex = function () {
        return this.length - 1;
    }

    function select(id) {
        return document.getElementById(id)
    }

    function start() {
        if (notStarted){
            setInterval(theLoop, 100)
            notStarted = false;
        }
    }

    function theLoop() {
        typed = myInput.value.split(/\s+/);
        myOutput.value = typed[typed.lastIndex()]
    }
```

Comment: Was this assigned to you as a task for education?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Use `"keyup"` to give the input time to update it's value
- Use the standard `Event.key` to read the inserted character
- Use `Array.prototype.pop()` to remove and return the last item from Array

```js
const words = [];

const memorizer = (ev) => {
  const inp = ev.target;
  const val = inp.value.trim();
 
  if(ev.key === ' ') {
    const valSpl = val.split(' ');
    words.push(valSpl[0]);
    inp.value = valSpl[1] || '';
  }

  if(ev.key === 'Backspace' && val === '' ) {
    inp.value = words.length ? words.pop() : '';
  }

  console.clear();console.log(words);
}

document.querySelector('#myInput').addEventListener('keyup', memorizer);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Type, use space and backspace">
```

Comment: the backspace is messed up when trying to edit a word

Comment: Type a word then try to delete the last char you entered, the backspace handler should check if you have a word and behave normally until you delete it completely then go back to the old one

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Well this achieve like 95% of the desired output, but it does not handle a situation when a user put the text insertion cursor in the middle of a text and then press space bar, in such situation the text after the insertion cursor should be the current text in the input field while the text before the insertion cursor should be added to the list of typed words.